# Convert string to datetime in Excel with individual format parameter (like TO_DATE, DateTime.ParseExact)?

Tags: excel, vba, datetime, type-conversion, to-date

Is there a function that converts a string to datetime using datetime format that is given as parameter in Excel?

You can imagine this like functions below in different platforms:

```
PLSQL: TO_DATE("20191301","YYYYDDMM")
C#: DateTime.ParseExact("20191301","YYYYDDMM", null)
```

Comment: DateValue takes a string and returns a true date.

Comment: In what sense is a function which takes input of specific types and returns a specific output a *generic* function? I suspect that you are not using "generic" with its standard meaning. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_function . In context, I suspect that you mean *built-in*.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the dates you want to convert

Comment: Just `=VALUE()` or =`DATEVALUE()`  as a worksheet formulae do exactly this. You don't need VBA.

Comment: I think these functions only can convert if the date string has a pre-defined format defined in the built-in function. Can I convert `29.10.2018:17:48:10` to a datetime?

Comment: I think the closest you can get to this kind of flexibility without VBA would be using the [text to columns feature under the Data tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePBbb.png) (though it will not work on `29.10.2018:17:48:10` because of the time part, but it will work if you first remove it). Where you can convert a entire column of strings (or numbers) to a date value at the [third step from the provided options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bAGO.png).

Comment: Why is there no sample data here for anyone to test? Just testing one string is not a good indicator of a valid solution. Please [edit] your question to include inputs/outputs. **Help us help you**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an attempt for a user-defined worksheet function:

- Function returns datetime value
- Supported format-string parts: yyyy, yy, mmm, MM, dd, hh, mm, ss
- am, a.m., a. m., pm, p.m., p. m. and their uppercases are all equivalent
- Only MM (month) and mm (minute) are case sensitive,
  MMM or mmm equals to Jan, Feb, ...
- 2-digit years below 80 are 20xx, 80 or above are 19xx
- Format-string must have the same length as the source string,
  otherwise returns #N/A error
- Filling characters can be blank, colon, double colon or else

Examples:
[image: TO_DATE DateTime.ParseExact examples in VBA]

EDIT:

```
Public Function TO_DATE(ByRef src As String, ByRef frmt As String) As Variant
    Dim y As Long, m As Long, d As Long, h As Long, min As Long, s As Long
    Dim am As Boolean, pm As Boolean
    Dim pos As Long

    If Len(src) <> Len(frmt) Then
        TO_DATE = CVErr(xlErrNA)  ' #N/A error
        Exit Function
    End If

    pos = InStr(1, frmt, "yyyy", vbTextCompare)
    If pos > 0 Then
        y = Val(Mid(src, pos, 4))
    Else: pos = InStr(1, frmt, "yy", vbTextCompare)
        If pos > 0 Then
            y = Val(Mid(src, pos, 2))
            If y < 80 Then y = y + 2000 Else y = y + 1900
        End If
    End If

    pos = InStr(1, frmt, "mmm", vbTextCompare)
    If pos > 0 Then
        m = month(DateValue("01 " & (Mid(src, pos, 3)) & " 2000"))
    Else: pos = InStr(1, frmt, "MM", vbBinaryCompare)
        If pos > 0 Then m = Val(Mid(src, pos, 2))
    End If

    pos = InStr(1, frmt, "dd", vbTextCompare)
    If pos > 0 Then d = Val(Mid(src, pos, 2))

    pos = InStr(1, frmt, "hh", vbTextCompare)
    If pos > 0 Then h = Val(Mid(src, pos, 2))
    If InStr(1, src, "am", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then am = True
    If InStr(1, src, "a.m.", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then am = True
    If InStr(1, src, "a. m.", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then am = True
    If InStr(1, src, "pm", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then pm = True
    If InStr(1, src, "p.m.", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then pm = True
    If InStr(1, src, "p. m.", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then pm = True
    If am And h = 12 Then h = 0
    If pm And h <> 12 Then h = h + 12

    pos = InStr(1, frmt, "mm", vbBinaryCompare)
    If pos > 0 Then min = Val(Mid(src, pos, 2))

    pos = InStr(1, frmt, "ss", vbTextCompare)
    If pos > 0 Then s = Val(Mid(src, pos, 2))

    TO_DATE = DateSerial(y, m, d) + TimeSerial(h, min, s)
End Function
```

Comment: Nice and simple parsing method. Kudos for keep the code short.

Comment: That's what I am looking for. Thanks a lot @Asger. Btw how can I add AM/PM capability to this code or can you update with this ability?

Comment: @AliTor I just edited it completely to get am/pm also.

Comment: This is a great function. It even works for  date string like "Wed, 29 Jan 2020 07:00:55 +0000":  TO_DATE(strDate, "Day, DD MMM YYYY hh:mm:ss +0000")

Answer (score -1):

May be this function returns result as you wish (you can modify to suit)

```
Function Convert2Date(s) As Date
Dim a           As Variant

a = Split(s, "/")
Convert2Date = DateSerial(a(2), a(1), a(0))
End Function
```

Comment: VBA is completely unnecessary here when there are built-in worksheet functions that will do this. Also, your function is assuming a format for the string, it would make more sense to be able to pass in the formatting string to specify the datatime format

Answer (score -3):

Based on the string you gave

Cell A1

```
29.10.2018:17:48:10
```

Use this

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND(":",A1)-1),".","/"))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(":",A1)+1,20))
```

Comment: Your solution only works with the example "29.10.2018:17:48:10" from the comments, but not with the example "20191301" from the question.

Comment: Correct but op was concerned with date and time, those function examples were date only and. The only string op explicitly defined that had date and time was the one in the comments.